# Count the first occurence of items inside arrays in MySQL JSON table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, date

I have a MySQL table where all the company sales for a given period are grouped by unit, date and, inside an array, all the sales representatives IDs that were involved in each sale.
The first sales_rep ID in each array shows which sales representative was responsible for closing each sale.
I am trying to elaborate a query that returns the unit, the date and the sales_rep ID for each sales representative that closed each sale.
It is ok if a sales_rep ID is shown more than once for given date.

What I have as input:

```
unit_id   date   unit_sales   sales_reps
427     2019-07-01   3     [["19823508","19823510",""],["23661230","23661227","23411261",""],["23411257","19823508",""]]
466     2019-07-26   2     [["23222763","23222766","26726848","26726849",""],["23222763",""]]
```

The desired output is:

```
unit_id   date      sales_rep
427     2019-07-01  19823508
427     2019-07-01  23661230
427     2019-07-01  23411257
466     2019-07-26  23222763
466     2019-07-26  23222763
```

Comment: There is no array datatype in MySQL. What is the datatype of column `sales_reps`?

Comment: @GMB Sorry, my mistake. It is a TEXT type

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment.

You should *really* consider fixing your data model. Storing structured data (csv, arrays, etc) in a text column will bite you in many ways. Typically, what you want to do here will necessarily involve a SQL with lot of complexity. This can be avoided by adopting a data model that better fits to your use case, for example:

- create a separate table to store the list of sales reps that were involved in each unit sale, with a boolean column that indicates which sales rep closed the sale; this seems like the *right way* to do it
- or, as an intermediate solution, transform your text column to a json column: this is less clean, but at least you could take advantage of json functions when accessing your data

Related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)